# Concatenate Two Cells Into One Cell Everytime There Are New Data Row Added

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm having trouble to create vba code to concatenate two cells into one cell. Those two cells consists of number and text.

I already create code to import data from another workbook and make vba paste the data to the next row available by using offset(1,0). But, i have no idea how to make vba concatenate each cells in column A & B into cells in column C.

I wish to concatenate it with underscore between them: Cells A_Cells B

Thank you in advance

```
'Import Data
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim openbook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        openbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NO PK").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        openbook.Close False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: How many columns are you copying? Only 2 (`A:B`) or more? If there are headers in the source sheet, don't you want to skip them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assign values to cells is more efficient than `Copy/PasteSpecial`.
- Apply formulas to concate Col A & B, then convert formulas to values.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.FormulaR1C1 property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formular1c1?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144137)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim openbook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        Dim srcRng As Range, RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
        Set srcRng = openbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        RowCnt = srcRng.Rows.Count
        ColCnt = srcRng.Columns.Count
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NO PK").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(RowCnt, ColCnt)
            .Value = srcRng.Value
            With .Columns(3)  ' Col C
                ' Apply formula to concate Col A, Col B
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2] & ""-"" & RC[-1]"
                ' Convert formulas to values
                .Formula = .Value
            End With
        End With
        openbook.Close False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 2):

### Import Data From Closed Workbook

```
Sub ImportData()

    ' Define constants.
    Const HEADER_ROWS As Long = 0 ' adjust!

    ' Open source file.
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", _
        Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
    If VarType(FileToOpen) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub ' dialog canceled
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Reference (set) the source objects.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim srg As Range:
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - HEADER_ROWS).Offset(HEADER_ROWS)
    End With
         
    ' Reference (set) the destination objects.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("NO PK")
    Dim dcell As Range: ' next available cell in column 'A'
    Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Dim drg As Range: ' same size as the source range
    Set drg = dcell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Copy values and close the source workbook.
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Concat columns 'A' and 'B' in 'C'.
    With drg.EntireRow
        .Columns("C").Value = dws.Evaluate(.Columns("A").Address _
            & "&""_""&" & .Columns("B").Address)
    End With
    
    ' Save the destination workbook.
    'dwb.save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```